# C# object null reference exception - not sure how to set array values

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, syntax, jagged-arrays

I guess I'm not setting the array correctly or something, but this throws a "nullreferenceexception" when it gets to the line where it actually sets the new array value to the color_table array (should be the 7th and 12th lines of what you see below).  How should I write this so that it works?

```
public int[] colors = new int[] { 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255 };

private int[][] color_table;

public void setcolors()
{
    this.color_table[0] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };
    for (int i = 1; i <= this.precision; i++) {
        int r = (((this.colors[1] - this.colors[0]) * ((i - 1) / (this.precision - 1))) + this.colors[0]);
        int g = (((this.colors[3] - this.colors[2]) * ((i - 1) / (this.precision - 1))) + this.colors[2]);
        int b = (((this.colors[5] - this.colors[4]) * ((i - 1) / (this.precision - 1))) + this.colors[4]);
        this.color_table[i] = new int[] { r, g, b };
    }
}
```

I've heard something about that you MUST initialize an array with its length before using it, but a) I don't know how to do that and b) I'm not sure if it's problem.  The issue there is that I don't know what the array length is going to be.  I tried this to no avail:

```
private int[this.precision][3] color_table;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your color_table is never initialized to any length... You should consider declaring it as [this.precision+1][3]

Comment: It underlines the [3] in red and says Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']' ... That's what I had tried before that didn't work.

Comment: @user1653653: You should leave the second arrays empty as in my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.color_table` has not been initialized. Hence you can't assign values to it.

Did you mean something like this:

```
public void setcolors()
{
    color_table = new int[precision + 1][];
    for (int i = 1; i <= this.precision; i++)
    {
        int r = (((this.colors[1] - this.colors[0]) * ((i - 1) / (this.precision - 1))) + this.colors[0]);
        int g = (((this.colors[3] - this.colors[2]) * ((i - 1) / (this.precision - 1))) + this.colors[2]);
        int b = (((this.colors[5] - this.colors[4]) * ((i - 1) / (this.precision - 1))) + this.colors[4]);
        this.color_table[i] = new int[] { r, g, b };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked :)  I didn't know you had to leave the second array empty and then my other problem was that I was trying to declare it outside of a method.

Comment: You have to declare it in the constructor (or a method) unless `precision` is a constant (`private const int precision = 4;`)

Answer (score 0):

try to use list if you don't know the length of your array

```
    List<int[]> color_table = new List<int[]>();
...
    color_table.Add(new int[] { r, g, b });
```